# Woocommerce Checkout Page Endless loading/spinner

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the Wordpress Woocommerce plugin and the "Check out" page gets stuck after the form is submitted with the correct info and won't continue to a confirmation page.

NOTE: I'm using an Authorize.NET gateway with the recommended test Credit Card numbers and I received the confirmation email. Also, no JS errors!

Any ideas?!

Comment: checked the dilithium crystals? no really the possibilities are endless, epically  with out seeing any code

Comment: The code is exactly what's in the checkout page via the plugin.Here's the site "http://natural.designessentials.com/". Add a few products to the cart. Click the number for the cart items in the header then click "Check out".

Here's the test credit card number for Master Card "5555555555554444".

Comment: sorry not going to go through all that code, with no ability to test it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76429910/infinite-checkout-loading I have the same problem! hello! did you solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you usingany other plugins, like pdf invoices?

I had this same problem which was caused bij some kind of language conflict. By switching Wordpress back to en_US in the wp-config file, the problem didnt occur anymore.

Comment: No, I realized it was a plugin that I left activated for the Star Ratings. I removed it since I wrote my own code to pull the star ratings. Thansk!

Comment: Having the same issue again. I could use your help.